# How to know the data type of value entered by user at runtime in textbox?

Tags: c#, textbox, gettype

How to know the data type of value entered by user at runtime in textbox?

My simple example:

I've tried it by using `GetType()`, but it was useless, it always shows `System.String`, whether I enter `int` or `String`.

Comment: value entered on a textbox should ideally return System.String.

Comment: `TextBox.Text` is a `System.String` type - it doesn't matter if you enter 1 or a, both are strings as far as the `TextBox` is concerned.

Comment: Then is there any way i can know what data type user has input at runtime . Like developer can able to know that user has entered int value in textbox or float value , etc..

Answer (score 1):

If the user has typed text into a textbox, that's *always* a string. It's never an int. You can *parse* the text as an integer, but the input itself is still text.

You could speculatively *try* to parse it in different ways:

```
int intValue;
if (int.TryParse(text, out intValue)
{
    ... use intValue, then return?
}

decimal decimalValue;
if (decimal.TryParse(text, out decimalValue)
{
    ... use decimalValue, then return?
}
```

But fundamentally you need to understand that the user input is *always* a string, and how you use that string is up to you.

Comment: yes fundamentally it's correct that text box will consider all input value as String But is there any way i can know the data type of input value in textbox by user at runtime?

Comment: @user2334930: Yes - you know that the data type is always string. I've given you sample code for seeing whether that string *can be parsed* as something else (you could try `double`, `DateTime` etc as well) but "the data type of input value in textbox" is always string. It really is as simple as that.