# determining a blank or integer or decimal in textbox

Tags: vb.net-2010

I cannot get my program to take the data in textbox and tell if it is blank, holds a integer or decimal number. If it is blank I want it to assign variable `PropAmt` to 0.00. If it has an integer, I want it to assign `PropAmt` to a decimal. And if it is a decimal, leave `PropAmt` alone.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim PropAMT = cdec(txtPropAMT.Text)
If txtPropAMT.Text = "" Then
    txtPropAMT.Text = 0.0
Else txtPropAMT.Text = CInt(txtPropAMT.Text) Then
    PropAMT = PropAMT & ".00"
ElseIf txtPropAMT.Text = CDec(txtPropAMT.Text) Then
    PropAMT = PropAMT
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

john,

here is what you been looking for 
 If txtBox.Text = String.Empty Then

```
    ElseIf (txtBox.Text Is GetType(Integer)) Then

    ElseIf (txtBox.Text Is GetType(Decimal)) Then

    End If
```

Comment: Everything works except for the integer part:     Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim PropAMT = txtPropAMT.Text
        If txtPropAMT.Text = "" Then
            txtPropAMT.Text = "0.0"
        ElseIf (txtPropAMT.Text Is GetType(Integer)) Then
            txtPropAMT.Text = PropAMT & ".00" 'If "123" is entered then the textbox changes from "123" to "123.00"
        ElseIf (txtPropAMT.Text Is GetType(Decimal)) Then
            txtPropAMT.Text = txtPropAMT.Text
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: what is the problem you are facing with integer

Comment: John, can you try from this Url  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294589/how-to-know-the-data-type-of-value-entered-by-user-at-runtime-in-textbox

Comment: The problem I am currently having is when I input 5 in a textbox the variable is assigned 5 and not 5.00 like I want. I want the program to notice if a integer has been input and if it has, the integer is converted to a decimal with  two zeros following the 5.

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

john here is it

```
    Dim intvalue As Integer
    Dim decValue As Decimal
    If txtBox.Text = String.Empty Then
        txtBox.Text = "0.0"
    ElseIf Integer.TryParse(txtBox.Text, intvalue) Then
        txtBox.Text += ".00"

    ElseIf Integer.TryParse(txtBox.Text, decValue) Then

    End If
```

let me know if you still face any problem.